# Не работает event.preventDefault() в битрикс 1с

Tags: jquery, битрикс

у меня возникла такая проблема- не работает event.preventDefault() в битрикс 1с. Вообщем, у меня есть такой код:

```js
 function pay() {
                
                $('#pay').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                  console.log("есть контакт");
                });
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form> 
    <button id="pay" name="pay"   class="btn btn-danger w-100 pay">
                  Заказать
    </button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не `preventDefault` не работает, а в принципе не назначается событие, поскольку функция `pay()` никак не вызывается. Вам просто нужно вызвать ее -- все заработает:

```js
function pay() {
  $('#pay').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("есть контакт");
  });
}

pay();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form> 
    <button id="pay" name="pay"   class="btn btn-danger w-100 pay">
                  Заказать
    </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант не подходит в моем случае. Почему то в шаблоне битрикса 1с не хочет работать. Я пробововал вызвать функцию так:   <button id="pay" onclick="pay();"  name="pay"   class="btn btn-danger w-100 pay">
              Заказать
              </button>, но не получается

Comment: @Pavel, консоль в браузере ругается на что-то?

Comment: @Pavel при моем варианте